# error C2065: 'AfxBeginThread' : undeclared identifier

Tags: windows-services, visual-c++, atl

I have a simple ATL Service in which I have included the following statement.

```
AfxBeginThread(WorkerThread, this, THREAD_PRIORITY_NORMAL, 0, 0);
```

But the compiler complains that

> error C2065: 'AfxBeginThread' :
>   undeclared identifier

But in MSDN i found that AfxBeginThread is found in AFXWIN.H

If I include AFXWIN.H, the compiler complains that

```
fatal error C1189: #error :  WINDOWS.H already included.  MFC apps must not #include <windows.h>
```

What am I missing here? Thanks.

PS: I am using Visual Studio 6.0 Enterprise Edition in Windows XP SP2.

Comment: What else are you including? If windows.h remove that

Comment: I m just trying to add AFXWIN.H. But the compiler says that above error C1189.. not sure why!! If i remove it, the other error appears.. C2065

Comment: We need to see what you have included

Comment: you should use `AfxBeginThread` on MFC projects.

Comment: @Nick D.. But ATL service is an MFC, project right? And I am using AfxBeginThread..

Comment: @bdhar, I have not tried ATL. Are you sure? If that's true, the wizard should have created a `StdAfx.h` file, which you can include in your modules. Also note that in some cases, precompiled headers cause compilation errors. Disabling precompiled headers or setting them to "automatic", on specific modules, usually solves the problems.

Comment: Thanks for comment, Nick. The wizard did create StdAfx.h. Let me check precompiled header issue and get back to you..

Comment: no, ATL isn't MFC. You need to add MFC support in wizard.http://support.microsoft.com/kb/173974

Comment: I see many people commenting and no real answers. I have a similar problem. Guess VC++ kicked my ass on this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An ATL project is NOT a MFC project using ATL. Use [_beginthreadex()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdzttdcb.aspx).

Comment: More recent versions of ATL offer AtlCreateThread function. Still as long as VS 6.0 is mentioned, OP have to be happy with _beginthreadex.